# Put a slash in the date of a EditText

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-edittext

I readed a lot of similar questions, but no one answers mine or can solve my problem. 
I have a EditText like this in the layout:

```xml
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:width="360dp"
        android:ems="5"
        android:hint="@string/ultimos4Dig"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I need that when the user are writing the numers of the month and year, a slash appear or disappearwhen he is writing. If he writes 2 numbers then a slash needs to appear. If he erases and its only one number, then the slash needs to disappear.

I need that in the editText appears the date as: 14/06

Here is my code but its not working.

```java
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        EditText editText2 = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
                if (text.length() == 2) {
                    text.append('/');
                }
            }
        });
```

FYI i made a class for a solution of this, thanks

Comment: change `android:inputType` from `number` to` text` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi! If i do this, then the keyboard changes to letters instead of numbers

Comment: I think date is not a number. why not using a date picker instead?

Comment: Hi thanks for you response, because my boss told me to do in this way. Insert a number with number keyboard

Comment: hey take a look at this post. i think it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889503/1656813

Comment: you need to *mask* your edittext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Masked Input Using EditText Widget in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912375/masked-input-using-edittext-widget-in-android)

Comment: 1 linear 3 edittext 2 textview
could make sense

Comment: Check this link it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56700789/9423249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you, after some days i got the solution, this class:

```java
public class EditMMYY extends AppCompatEditText implements TextWatcher
{
    private String sPrev = "";
    private int iMon = 0;
    private int iYear = 0;

    private void InitValue()
    {
        setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});
        setHint("MM/YY");
    }

    public EditMMYY(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        InitValue();
    }

    public EditMMYY(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        InitValue();
    }

    public EditMMYY(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        InitValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        // Chequeo que el ingreso sea MM/YY
        String sNew = s.toString();
        int newLen = sNew.length();

        if(sNew.equals(sPrev))
        {
            return;
        }
        switch(newLen)
        {
            case 0:
                iMon = 0;
                iYear = 0;
                sPrev = sNew;
                break;
            case 1:
                iMon  = Integer.parseInt(sNew);
                iYear = 0;
                if(sPrev.length() == 0 && iMon > 1)
                {    // Si se escribe un número mayor que 1, lo tomo como mes
                    sPrev = String.format("%02d/", iMon);
                }
                else
                {
                    sPrev = sNew;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                iMon  = Integer.parseInt(sNew);
                iYear = 0;
                if(sPrev.length() == 1)
                {
                    // Si ya es un mes válido, lo completo, sino dejo
                    // sPrev sin cambios hasta que se ingrese algo válido
                    if(iMon >= 1 && iMon <= 12)
                    {
                        sPrev = String.format("%02d/", iMon);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sPrev = sNew;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                iMon  = Integer.parseInt(sNew.substring(0, 2));
                iYear = 0;
                if(sPrev.length() == 2)
                {
                    iMon = Integer.parseInt(sNew.substring(0, 2));
                    iYear = Integer.parseInt(sNew.substring(2, 3));
                    sPrev = String.format("%02d/%d", iMon, iYear);
                }
                else
                {
                    sPrev = sNew;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
                iMon = Integer.parseInt(sNew.substring(0, 2));
                iYear = Integer.parseInt(sNew.substring(3, newLen));
                sPrev = sNew;
                break;
            default:
                sPrev = sNew;
                break;
        }
        setText(sPrev);
        setSelection(sPrev.length());
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

    }

    public int getMon()
    {
        return iMon;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return iYear;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Masked Edit Text:

https://github.com/santalu/mask-edittext

In Moudle build gradle add:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

In app build gradle add:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.github.santalu:maskara:1.0.0'
}
```

And in your layout you can use MaskEditText:

```
<com.santalu.maskedittext.MaskEditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="248dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:width="360dp"
    android:ems="5"
    android:hint="@string/ultimos4Dig"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:mask="##/##"/>
```

Comment: Hi, when I try to implement this, when I compile shows this error: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-28:19 to override.

Answer (score 2):

Add your logic in `onTextChanged` instead of `afterTextChanged`

Please try below code :

```
editText2 .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String str=editText2 .getText().toString();
                int textLength=editText2 .getText().length();
                if (textLength == 3) {
                    if (!str.contains("/")) {
                        editText2 .setText(new StringBuilder(editText2 .getText().toString()).insert(str.length() - 1, "/").toString());
                        editText2 .setSelection(editText2 .getText().length());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Hello, its doesnt! writes a lot of slashs

Answer (score 1):

I think this got the solution to some extent. Add `app:endIconMode="clear_text"` to the TextInputlayout.

```
 dateOfBirth.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.length() == 2 || charSequence.length() == 5) {
                    if (!Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2})/").matcher(charSequence).matches()) {
                        dateOfBirth.getEditText().setText(new StringBuilder(dateOfBirth.getEditText().getText().toString()).insert(charSequence.length(), "/").toString());
                        dateOfBirth.getEditText().setSelection(dateOfBirth.getEditText().getText().length());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```